# Download files from S3 without AWSSDK.S3 or other dependencies C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm currently downloading files from S3 using AWSSDK.S3. I download the files as follows:

```
TransferUtility fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(new AmazonS3Client("xxxx", "xxxx"));

fileTransferUtility.Download("test/testdata.parquet", "test-bucket", "testdata.parquet");
```

I'm curious if it's possible to download this file from S3 without using AmazonS3Client or the AWSSDK.S3 dependency? I'm restricted with regard to the nuget packages I can use and would like to download files from S3 without any additional dependencies.

Comment: I assume your bucket is not public?  Also, you may want to elaborate on why you are restricted from using (certain?) nuget packages, as there might be other alternatives that allow you to continue to use the AWS SDK.

Comment: Most cloud SDKs are wrappers over a documented REST API. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/Welcome.html

Answer (score 0):

If you know the bucket(s) and file names and have proper S3 permissions you should be able to download the files using HTTPS.

[AWS Bucket Access guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-bucket-intro.html)